# Nesting variadic template

Tags: c++, nested, variadic-templates

I have two classes that utilize initialize lists. One is a Vector styled class that hold a list of values.

Vec.h:

```
template< typename T, int nDimensions = 2 >
class Vec{
    private:
        std::array< T, nDimensions > elements_;
    public:
        template <typename... U>
        Vec(U... ts) : elements_{ ts... } {}
}
```

Then when used:

```
typedef Vec< int, 2 > Vec2i;
Vec2i twoi = { 1,2 };
Vec2i twoi2 = twoi; //I have copy constructor and other methods finished.
```

This class works all fine and dandy, however when I try to use this class with my Matrix styled class, I cant figure out the correct syntax for its constructor.

```
template< typename T, int X,int Y>
class Mat {
   private:
     std::array< Vec<T, X>, Y > elements_;
}
```

Id like to use it like so:

```
typedef Mat<int, 3,3> Mat3i;
Mat3i threemat = {  {1,2,3},
                    {4,5,6},
                    {7,8,9}};
```

Now, iv tried using initializer lists as the constructor with some success, but I cant figure out the syntax to pass the sub lists along.

```
Mat(std::initializer_list<Vec<T, X>> values) {
    for (auto& t : values) {
        //What goes here?
    }
}
```

Iv also tried iteration over the list and assigning them manually, but thats a no go.

Its also worth noting that its important that these classes have consecutive chunks of memory for there lists, and no other variables. Otherwise id be using other types instead of std::array. (For casting and union purposes.)

I'm debating if I need to reinterpret cast each value as a Vec then copy over the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alternative:

```
Mat(std::initializer_list<Vec<T, X>> values) {
    std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), elements_.begin());
}
```

Comment: That also works quite well and is probably the better answer. One small question, how do you prevent narrowing/widening conversions with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.

```
Mat(std::initializer_list<Vec<T, X>> values) {
    int i = 0;
    for (auto& t : values) {
        elements_[i++] = t;
    }
}
```